# Unable to find Presence insight sample store environment

Tags: ibm-cloud, demo, presenceinsights

I have signed up for the presence Insight demo mentioned in the below link but unable to see the sample store environment in my bluemix dashboard. I have followed the documentation to add the Presence Insight service in my space.

[Tour IBM Presence Insight](http://www.ibm.com/mobilefirst/us/en/presence-insights.html)

Could you please guide? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can see a detail guide about Presence Insight into bluemix documentation: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/presenceinsights/index.html.

In particular, if you want a guide of iOS SDK, you can see:
https://presenceinsights.ibmcloud.com/pidocs/mobile/iossdk

Otherwise, if you want a guide of Android SDK, you can see:
https://presenceinsights.ibmcloud.com/pidocs/mobile/android

Some demos you can find them here: https://github.com/presence-insights

Comment: There are any example:
1) IBM Presence Insights Beacon Sensing - It's show how to leverage the Presence Insights SDK for beacon sensing for IOS (Swift).

2) IBM Presence Insights Device Registration - It's show how to leverage Presence Insights SDK (device registration) for IOS(swift). 

3) MobileFirst Platform - Presence Insights Eventing With Node.js

4) IBM Presence Insights Beacon Configuration Tool - It's use the ibeacon technology and leverage the Presence Insights SDK to easily detect beacons in your store and quickly add them to your Presence Insights Instance.

Comment: Thanks for the samples. I am looking for the ***visit our sample store environment** and **Move your virtual visitors** demo features mentioned in this [link](http://www.ibm.com/mobilefirst/us/en/presence-insights.html).

Comment: In that guide, there is only the way for how to create a sample using a IBM Presence Insights; If you want examples preloaded you can see what I've linked before.

Comment: Can I have a sample store environment with floor maps as mentioned in the [VT cycling demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARCqmQSPj08&feature=youtu.be)? I am trying to quickly develop a demo app that communicate with the Presence Insight service. If I gets a sample store environment as mentioned in your video, I think I can save the time in creating and configuring organization, site, floors, upload floor plans, floor maps, beacons etc. in the dashboard. Looking forward to your support. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to:

1. login to Bluemix go to catalog
       (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/?search=presence%20insight) 
       click on the service "Presence Insight";
2. When the service creation page opens up create the service with the
       app field value equal to    "leave unbound".
3. Once you have done it you can go to the Dashboard    page and see
       under the services section the newly created service    listed.

I have tried it right now to verify if any problem occurs but everything is ok: I was able to create the service.

Comment: Where can I find the **sample store environment** mentioned in this [link](http://www.ibm.com/mobilefirst/us/en/presence-insights.html).

Comment: I missed a part of the problem. @Simone Rutigliano answer is a perfect reference for that part.

Comment: Unable to view any information captured on the analytics dashboard. Site visits, visits by zone, visit density, heat map, device activities  none of these details are displayed on the Presence Insights analytics dashboard for my site. Even the total number of sites is displayed as zero. I have created a site, uploaded a sample floor map, marked a zone and configured a beacon for the zone through the management console. can see the inbound beacon events on the analytics dashboard under operations tab. Am I missing some configuration? Or is this an issue with the PI service dashboard?